# О женщине: хостесс или хостесса?

Tags: грамотная-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Воркование донны Терезы в свободные минутки с вниманием выслушивает хостесс – невестка, приятная женщина средних лет, она же управляющая рестораном".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если внедрять такое слово (оно неизбежно и в телевизор перекочует вместо "ведущих"), то по обычной для принцесс с поэтессами схеме (хост у них тоже есть). А почему не назвать её администраторшей, управляющей?

Comment: Потому что автор уже давно живёт в Италии, оевропеился, а нам (мне) слово известно именно по детективу. Я погуглила *хостес*  - это нечто большее, чем администратор.

Comment: В оригинале "размер" не имеет значения: в английском это чисто условный и обычно временный статус человека, олицетворяющего "принимающую (гостей) сторону" в каком-л. мероприятии и проявляющего публичную активность "хозяина" (напр. ведущий телепередачи), на него этим словом только ссылаются по поводу ведения мероприятия.

Comment: Всё, всё - автору на обозрение и изучение!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если слово не зафиксировано, то у вас руки развязаны — пишите, как нравится. Я бы писал на русский лад — хостесса.